# Function doesn't seem to modify array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a program that is supposed to take in an input of zeroes and ones and assign them into an array. Then it passes the array to edge function and formats it in the following way.

1. Assign a 1 to the output bit pattern whenever two consecutive bits (one bit and it’s
   previous bit) are different
2. Assign a 0 to the output bit pattern whenever two consecutive bit (one bit and it’s
   previous bit) are the same
3. Assign 0 to the first output bit since there is no previous bit for the first bit

The problem is that when the array is passed to the function and printf is called, it simply prints out the original input. I've looked at it from different angles and can't seem to see whats wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void edge(int n, int a1[], int a2[])
{
    int i = 1;
    a2[0] = 0;
    int last = a1[i-1];
    printf("%d", a2[0]);
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(last == a1[i])
        {
                a2[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                a2[i] = 1;
        }
    printf("%1d", a2[i]);
}
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int num;

    int array1[8];
    int array2[8]={0};

    printf("Enter an 8-digit barcode: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        scanf("%1d", &num);
        if(num == 1)
        {
                array1[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Output: ");

    edge(8, array1, array2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't update the value you give to `last` in your loop ; could your problem originate there ?

Comment: Arrays in C (and C++) are zero- write

Comment: What do you mean by update it?

Comment: Since you talk in your explanation about "2 consecutive bits", probably you'd want to add `last = a1[i]` just after your call to `printf` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Got it! just got rid of last completely and switched it out in the loop for a1[i-1]

Comment: You should also initialize the first array `int array1[8]= {0};` or add an else statement when inputting the values, like `array1[i] = num == 1 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour if the input is not all 1's, because you don't handle that case and pass garbage in `array1`

Comment: @Dustynana: Don't delete necessary parts of your question just because you have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't update `last` within the loop, you'll always compare the values stored in `a2[]` with the same value, which does not seem to be your aim.
Thus updating `last` in the loop.

```
void edge(int n, int a1[], int a2[])
{
    int i;
    a2[0] = 0;
    int last;
    printf("%d", a2[0]);
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        last = a1[i-1];
        if(last == a1[i])
            a2[i] = 0;
        else 
            a2[i] = 1;
        printf("%1d", a2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're completely right, i did this just now and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: got rid of last completely and switched it out in the loop for a1[i-1], where the if statement is.